# Splitting numbers in a column into digits in separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a csv file that looks like this ( visits can't be aggregated because they refer to days, for example 2=Monday, 3=Tuesday..etc)

[image]

I want to split the "visits" column so that I will have each digit in a separate column. Something like this:

[image]

How can I do this with python? I want to have as many columns as the number of digits. I have 1000 rows

I started wit this code but it just didn't work.

```
import pandas as pd
 file=pd.read_csv('file.csv')

data = []
with open('file.csv', 'r') as fh:
for line in fh:
 data.append(line.split())

 data = dict(zip(*data))
 d = { v for in [int(c)]) 
data['visits'][1:])]}
d['ID'] = data['ID']
d['visits'] = data['visits'][0]
data = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: First of all: are you sure that the number of digits is always the same? If that's not the case, then you may want to do something else (e.g. apply a function on that column).

Comment: @pazqo by looking at it ,I would say no. It's a large file ( 1000 rows). That's why I want to use Python .

Comment: You want to split digits or _numbers_? Splitting digits seems pointless. Also, can you please paste some data in text? Pictures do not help, contrary to popular belief.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I have a column that has more than 100 number and I want to split this column so that each number will have its own column

Comment: Then use `df.visits.str.split(expand=True)`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I get this error "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'visits'

Comment: @Supern92 Change `df.visits` to `df['visits']`, or whatever your column name is (idk, you should know). Look down for fleshed out answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str.split`:

```
df

   ID       visits
0   1   12 1 40 50
1   2  56 2 567 34
2   3   4 5 345 78

visits = df['visits'].str.split(expand=True).add_prefix('visit_')    
visits

  visit_0 visit_1 visit_2 visit_3
0      12       1      40      50
1      56       2     567      34
2       4       5     345      78
```

Next, concatenate `visits` with `ID`:

```
df = pd.concat([df[['ID']], visits], 1)    
df

   ID visit_0 visit_1 visit_2 visit_3
0   1      12       1      40      50
1   2      56       2     567      34
2   3       4       5     345      78
```

---

If you want each digit of each number separately, you would chain a `df.apply` call. Furthermore, to replace `8` with `0`, use `df.replace`.

```
visits = df['visits'].str.replace('\s+', '')\
           .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x))).add_prefix('visit_')\
           .replace('[89]', 0, regex=True)
visits

  ID visit_0 visit_1 visit_2 visit_3 visit_4 visit_5 visit_6 visit_7
0   1       1       2       1       4       0       5       0     NaN
1   2       5       6       2       5       6       7       3       4
2   3       4       5       3       4       5       7       0     NaN
```

Note that each column is a column of strings (`object` type). However, if you want them as integers, you'll want to get rid of `NaN`s. If you're okay with dropping `NaN` columns, this solution simplifies a bit.

```
visits = df.visits.str.replace('\s+', '')\
           .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x)))\
           .dropna(axis=1).add_prefix('visit_').astype(int) % 8
visits

   visit_0  visit_1  visit_2  visit_3  visit_4  visit_5  visit_6
0        1        2        1        4        0        5        0
1        5        6        2        5        6        7        3
2        4        5        3        4        5        7        0
```

You'll still need to concatenate `visits` with `df.ID` using `pd.concat`.